# Calculation in Javascript without rounding decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, math, jquery-calculation

Guys I got a text box wherein users may enter valid decimal numbers.

And later I have to do calculations with this decimal number without rounding it.

Currently I am working as

```
 var pricePerItemExVat = Math.round($("#InnerCaseWsp").val()) / Math.round($("#InnerCaseItemSellUnit").val());
```

How do I do the same without rounding the number ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you used `Math.round` to get numbers from strings.

Just parse the strings to numbers using [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) :

```
var pricePerItemExVat = parseFloat($("#InnerCaseWsp").val()) / parseFloat($("#InnerCaseItemSellUnit").val());
```

Comment: Actually `parseFloat` isn't even necessary because `/` will automatically cast it into a number (as defined in the spec.)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 In **that specific case** yes, but OP says he has other computations and I guess some of them involve other operators, for example `+`.

Comment: Well if he does have `+` in his other code then I believe `parseFloat` is indeed needed... or just a `+` in front would also do it.